# AS3 how to ignore previous if statements

Tags: if-statement, actionscript-3

I;m a bit of a newbie in porgramming, and i'm not so sure if my question is clear enough. Anyways I have this code that spawns in a portal once a certain score is reached.
How do I make it so that newPortal() will only spawn if score is equal to 5, newPortal_2() will only spawn if score is 10 and so on? What's happening is that all portals spawn once the if conditions are met, but that is not what I intend to do. Please help...

```
        score += 1;
        score_TF.text = String(score);
        
    

        if (score== 5)
        {
            newPortal();
            warpsound.play();
            portal.visible = true;
        }
    
        if (score== 10)
        {
            newPortal_2();
            warpsound.play();
            portal2.visible = true;
        }
        if (score== 15)
        {
            newPortal_3();
            warpsound.play();
            portal3.visible = true;
        }
```

Comment: This piece of code does not seem to have any problems. Each respective block should execute ONLY if the conditions are met. You may replace 2nd and 3rd **if**s with **else if**, but I doubt there will be any difference.

Comment: @Organis I've made it now where spawning a new portal removes the previous portal. Although my question now is, can portal.visible= false remove the function newPortal()? I mean like newPortal() won't work anymore.

Comment: Sure. Just check if the respective portal exists or not before creating a new one.